# Java - How to parse this String using RegEx

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

So I have this string and I want to parse it. Normally I would use string.split() for it but it's a bit complicated so I thought that may using regex is better in this case. But I am not too familar with regex. Maybe you girls/guys could help me out.

My string looks like this:

```
PING :sendak.freenode.net
```

Or like this

```
:username!~user@hostname.tld PRIVMSG #channelname :test
```

And should be parsed into it's components prefix, username, command, channel, text.

Example:

```
PING :sendak.freenode.net
```

Should be:

```
prefix=[] username=[] command=[PING] channel=[] text=[sendak.freenode.net]
```

and the string:

```
:username!~user@hostname.tld PRIVMSG #channelname :test
```

should be parsed to:

```
prefix=[username!~user@hostname.tld] username=[username] command=[PRIVMSG] channel=[#channelname] text=[test]
```

In the end I have to fill out these variables:

```
message.prefix = "";
message.username = "";
message.command = "";
message.channel = "";
message.text = "";
```

I am spliting a line at a time!

Fairly obvious that it's gonna be a small IRC chat.

The problem  I expierence is that it can start with a ":" but does not have to.Thus making it fairly complex to realising using several splits().

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to parse out? What have you attempted or tried?

Comment: There are many solutions for your problem, but here is a possible one: Use the Splitter class, from the [guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter). You should try splitting one line at a time.

Comment: How is `split()` any more complicated than regex when `split()` takes a regex?

Comment: I don't want to cut something 'out'. Above I have 2 example messages and the line below it is how it should get parsed. My current attempts are poor and not working. I basically started a to split at the ":" then splited the second last element of the resulting array at the spaces. And then I stopped because I ran into the issue with the : in the beginning of a line.

Comment: Better yet, can you provide an example of how the output should look after it is parsed?

Comment: @c-pid Sounds almost like you could use a parser more than regex. *Might* be easier than working out corner cases, but I don't know...

Comment: @user3580294 sorry my bad. Bad expression on my side. I tried splitting on single characters, meaning something like string.split(":") and then I took a string from the resulting array and splitted it at the space etc. Then I had to include several if chases depending on the type of message and if it starts with a : or not. So I am seeking a easier solution that will return me the splitted string in the parts I need it to be.

Comment: @c-pid Unfortunately, I won't be too much help, as I'm not very familiar with IRC. Sorry...

Comment: Depending on how complex it gets, a recursive descent parser might work, but that could also be pretty overkill if I'm overestimating the complexity of IRC commands...

Comment: I changed the OP to make it more clear.

Comment: @Danix I can't use any external libaries sadly. Also I am splitting one line at a time. I changed the OP to be more precise.

Comment: @c-pid What are the delimiters separating each part of a line?

Comment: Are those lines the only two possibilities for output in your log file? Can you guarantee the logs will output the same way all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex may help you: **"(:?((.*)![^ ]*))? ?([^ ]*) (#([^ ]*) )?(:(.*))?"**:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Message{
    public String prefix = "";
    public String userName = "";
    public String command = "";
    public String channel = "";
    public String text = "";

    public Message(String line){
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(:?((.*)![^ ]*))? ?([^ ]*) (#([^ ]*) )?(:(.*))?").matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()){
            prefix = matcher.group(2) != null? matcher.group(2): "";
            userName = matcher.group(3) != null? matcher.group(3): "";
            command = matcher.group(4) != null? matcher.group(4): "";
            channel = matcher.group(6) != null? matcher.group(6): "";
            text = matcher.group(8) != null? matcher.group(8): "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("prefix=[%s] username=[%s] command=[%s] channel=[%s] text=[%s]", prefix, userName, command, channel, text);
    }
}


public class TestRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Message("PING :sendak.freenode.net"));
        System.out.println(new Message(":username!~user@hostname.tld PRIVMSG #channelname :test"));
        System.out.println(new Message("username!~user@hostname.tld PRIVMSG #channelname :test"));
    }
}
```